# How to inject HttpClient in module mock

Tags: angular, unit-testing

For testing I want to mock my dependency module `NavigationService` with a mock. In the mock class I need to make HTTP requests, so I need the `HttpClient` to be injected into my mock class. This is my `beforeEach`:

```
beforeEach (() => {
  TestBed.configureTestingModule ({
    imports: [HttpClient, RouterTestingModule],
    providers: [
      {
        provide: NavigationService, useClass: class {
          constructor (httpClient: HttpClient) {
          }
          method1() {
            return this.httpClient.get('/some-url');
          }
        },
      },
    ]
  });
});
```

But that does not work, it gives an error on every test:

```
Error: Can't resolve all parameters for class_1: (?).
```

So how do I correctly inject `HttpClient` into the mock class?

Comment: Should not you import HttpClientModule instead of HttpClient?

Comment: did you mean HttpClientTestingModule? that does not work, too

Comment: What do you mean *"does not work"*? `HttpClientTestingModule` is certainly what you're looking for, see e.g. https://angular.io/guide/http#testing-http-requests. But it's not at all clear to me what's going on in your TestBed configuration; is `NavigationService` the class under test? Why are you trying to rebuild it inline like that?! If you're trying to mock out `NavigationService` to test a collaborator, then: 1. where's that collaborator; and 2. why do you need `HttpClient` at all, given that it's encapsulated within the mocked-out dependency?

Comment: Specifically: *"In the mock class I need to make HTTP requests"* - could you expand on why you think that's the case?

Comment: does not work means I get the error message I mentioned.

Answer (score -1):

You need to inject the `HttpTestingController` to use the mock of `HttpClient`. Here's how I do it (my `ProductService` makes an HTTP request in `getProducts()`):

```
describe('ProductService', () => {
  let productService: ProductService;
  let httpMock: HttpTestingController;

  beforeEach(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      imports: [HttpClientTestingModule],
      providers: [ProductService]
    });

    productService = TestBed.get(ProductService);
    httpMock = TestBed.get(HttpTestingController);
  });

  it('should successfully get products', async(() => {
    const productData: Product[] = [{ "id":"0", "title": "First Product", "price": 24.99 }];
    productService.getProducts()
      .subscribe(res => expect(res).toEqual(productData));

    // Emit the data to the subscriber
    let productsRequest = httpMock.expectOne('/data/products.json');
    productsRequest.flush(productData);
  }));
```